# shared preferences object data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating shared preferences objects as follows:

```
sh_subjecturi = context.getSharedPreferences("MyCourse__Set", Context.MODE_APPEND);

Editor editor_subjuri_set;

editor_subjuri_set = sh_subjecturi.edit();
```

Next in the loop, I am putting the data using the editor object.

When I am executing my program , I am getting the `MyCourse_Set.xml` file but the data is not in order (jumbling format i.e chapters are not coming in order as available).

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your point right, the `SharedPreferences` is basically a `Map<Key, Value>` Class (Check [SharedPreferences - Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)), which is designed without order inside as you can always find `value` via `key`.

Therefore if you need an ordered data, you can save them into a `List` then put them into `SharedPreferences`

Comment: is it possible to store a list into sharedpreferences ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille yes absolutely. All u need is to serialise them. You can have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: i sure will :) thanks for the info. this is something new for me :)